# How to detect memory leaks on windowed (gtk,qt,etc) applications?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I used to use valgrind to find memory leaks in my applications.
But when i use gtk/qt/glut or any "windowing" application valgrind is spamming like an evil.

I've found out that in these libraries are no real memory leaks - but how then detect real memory leaks ?

Comment: Have you tried a [suppression file](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto)?

Comment: You can use Deleaker instead of Valgrind - It's similar debugger but for Windows.

Comment: Qt uses many global objects/singletons which make memory leak checking a PITA.  It may be the same for gtk/glut as well.  I have in the past manually called the destructor code for the singletons at program exit, thus removing many of the false positives.

Comment: @syplex good implementation of singleton is static instance in function. It will be automatically freed. But I dont know what impl qt/gtk uses. It doesnt matter for me now.

Comment: @quarry that implementation of singletons will suffer from this problem.  Static instances inside of functions will be allocated before main (in non-deterministic order) and free'd after program exit (in non-deterministic order) and will show up as a false positive in many memory leak checkers.

Comment: another tool on linux is pmap which will show you the memory of the proc and give detailed output as it is running. example pmap -x 21000

Comment: @SamMiller could you re-post it as an answer ? (this is exactly what solved it and i dont want to answer my own question with your credits :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [suppression file](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto) to silence warnings in third party libraries you cannot control.